# How do I convert part of a string to int in C#?

Tags: c#, string, int

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string foo = "jason123x40";
    char[] foo2 = foo.ToCharArray();
    string foo3 = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < foo2.Length; i++)
    {
        int num = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(foo2[i].ToString(), out num);
        if (num != 0)
        {
            foo3 += num.ToString();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(foo3);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So lets say I have a string called "john10smith250". The result should be "10250". However I would get "125" instead with my code.

The reason I filtered out the 0 was because I didn't want any non numeric characters to be treated as a zero.

Is there a better way to convert a part of a string into an int?

Comment: You're explicitly *not* counting `'0'`, so you shouldn't be surprised that you don't have any in your result... Also, `char.IsNumber(char)`.  You're using TryParse incorrectly.  If it failed it returns false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using LINQ :

```
var myString = "john10smith250";
var myNumbers = myString.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray();
var myNewString = new String(myNumbers);
```

Comment: yeah, isn't that cool =)

Comment: Uhm, where is x defined? I'm not really sure on how to use LINQ.

Comment: @puretppc `x` represents each charachter in your string

Comment: @puretppc, if you are asking where is the `var x = blah` there is none.  Its declared in the `x =>` and used inline.  Its scope is only in those parens.

Comment: @puretppc, there's a lambda expression in the query. It doesn't have to be declared somewhere else. More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @puretppc, if you don't know linq and lambda statements,you should learn.as you see they are cool and they save you from lot of work :)

Comment: Yup I'll try :) Btw, are they efficient in terms of CPU?

Comment: @puretppc I'm not expert on efficiency but it depends I think.In your case probably it doesn't matter.But on largest lists it should matter.Less code would be less painful

Answer (score 4):

You've got a couple of good solutions that change the approach and shorten your code. For completeness, here is how you make your code work.

Your code assumes that if the `num` is zero, the parse has failed:

```
int num = 0;
Int32.TryParse(foo2[i].ToString(), out num);
if (num != 0) // This is wrong
{
    foo3 += num.ToString();
}
```

You need to change the code like this:

```
int num = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(foo2[i].ToString(), out num))
{
    foo3 += num.ToString();
}
```

The reason your code did not work was that you ignored the return value of `TryParse`. It returns `false` if the parse fails, or `true` if the parse succeeds, even if the number being parsed is zero. In fact, that's the reason behind `TryParse` taking an `out` parameter (as opposed to returning the value directly, the way the `Int32.Parse` does).

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using `Regx`

`\d+` is the `regex` for an integer number.

So

```
string outputstring = Regex.Match(yourstring, @"\d+").Value;
```

will give you that number as a string. `Int32.Parse(outputstring)` will then give you the number.

or you can do like this

go through the string and use `Char.IsDigit`

```
string a = "str123";
string b = string.Empty;
int val;
for (int i=0; i< a.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(a[i]))
        b += a[i];
}
if (b.Length>0)
{
    val = int.Parse(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
var str= "jason123x40";
var number=  str.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)).Select(x => x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close to what you have there...

```
int parseNumbersFromString(string data)
{
    string number = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    {
        if(char.IsDigit(data[i]))
            number += data[i];
    }
    return Convert.ToInt32(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You can use index to access a char in a string
*IsDigit check if this char is a digit then append it to the string foo2 if condition is true

```
string foo = "jason0123x40";
string foo2 = "";

for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(foo[i]))
        foo2 += foo[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(foo2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're a little late but thanks anyways for this. +1 :)

Comment: No problem, I just notice that you are not familiar with Lambda expression and Linq and tried to give you more efficient alternative.

Comment: Yeah I consider both of them. At least it's helpful in case people find this question so they can try whichever one they like. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as follows:

```
string foo = "jason123x40";
string foo3 = Regex.Replace(foo, @"\D", "");
```